# How can I make mvc action call from WordPress using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I make below action item called from non asp.net application like wordpress? How can I do it with jquery because I not able to call it on my local machine. Do I have to write custom router for it?

```
public ActionResult CreateUser(String first_name, String last_name, String email, String company)
 {
    //implementation
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the full URL for that action?  It would be something like `/controller/action` by default.  You can send any GET or POST request with the values to that URL to invoke that.  For example:

```
http://servername/controller/CreateUser?first_name=John&last_name=Smith&email=john%40acme.com&company=Acme
```

How you invoke that URL from some other client-side technology is immaterial to the ASP.NET MVC server-side code.  Any request which routes to that action and contains the expected values will get there.